# What do you mean by "The Active X control cannot be instantiated" error in visual c++?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, activex

When i am trying to open a `Visual C++` project. Two following pop-up occurs:

1) `ActiveX control cannot be instantiated`

2) `Active X control not registered on this computer`

I searched for this error and got a solution i.e. Add Active X to your `Visual C++` project.
I am newbie in `Visual C++`, just started to debug a project. Please tell me how should i do that?

Anyhow i opened the project and make build it. Now when i tried to execute the "Application.exe" then nothing happened. I think this is all happening because of this `Active X control` error.

Apart from scenario please tell me some following points:

a) What is the use of `Active x control in visual c ++`?
b) Is there any way to convert `visual C++` project to `C#`?

I know that it is a big question to ask but any hint will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Interop dll from C++ dll you can add the Interop dll to ur C# project.

First if you have the C++ dll, then you you can use those dll into C# Project. follow Below methods

Open Visual Studio Command Prompt (Run as Administartor)
Change the Path where the dll located (cd C:/User/Douments/Visual Studio 2010/)
type the command

```
tlbimp CACDirect.dll /transform:dispret /out:Interop.CACDirect.dll
```

You will get result like this below.

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter 4.0.30319.1 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

TlbImp : Type library imported to C:\Users\082043\Desktop\Interop.CACDirect.dll
```

Comment: Whey you Create Interop dll from C++ DLL, Now Interop dll acts like CLR dll, you can reference into your C#,Vb Project. Then there won't be any more problems

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ required some licensed control like MS Chart Control, it require a design-time license during design time and a run-time license during runtime. The only known way to get the design-time license for MS Chart Control is to install Visual Studio(6.0 in your case). You can try to re-install VS6 but there is no guarantee it will work. A workaround could be provide a custom dialog box that provides the ability to change the properties that you desire. Then you can make calls to the object at runtime to change those properties (without using the control's licensed property pages). A solution may be upgrade to the latest Visual Studio, this is useful but may not always resonable to all end-users, so you can make the decision on your own.